# How to create video visualizations / sound responses for songs

Tags: video-editor, kdenlive

Simply I'm wanting to create music visualization videos for songs I make for youtube (like a stereoscope). I know it can be done using templates for Adobe After Effects on Windows machines. Is there any software / plugins for Ubuntu that would provide this? I use Kdenlive for general video editing but it doesn't look like it provides the kind of functionality for this requirement. I've googled quite a bit but to no avail.

Something like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptICQtESe64

Answer (score 0):

There is a standalone program with lots of variables to tweak: [cthugha](http://www.afn.org/~cthugha/)

The tricky part is that is's really old, last release 1999 - but I think is was pretty independent of libraries, even has a DOS version - so it's possible it will still run on modern linux.

The original ftp server seems to be down, but you can find the Llinux version as 
"cthugha-L-1.4.tar.gz" with Google.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Astrofox [a page for Astrofox download](https://astrofox.io/download)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1187152)